# Pass different arguments to ThreadPool.apply_async() method in python

Tags: python, multithreading, arguments, threadpool, pool

I want to pass different arguments to ThreadPool.apply_async() method. How I can do it? I thought it was done in the following way, but I was wrong.
Could I use Thread instead? 
Thank you in advance

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import multiprocessing

def testMethod(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    print(f"{arg1} - {arg2} - {arg3}"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    for t in range(1000):
        pool.apply_async(testMethod, t, arg2, arg3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type hints on the method signature in [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/3/multiprocessing/pool.pyi#L39-L44) show, that postional arguments must be supplied as an iterable:

```
def apply_async(self,
                func: (...) -> _T,
                args: Iterable = ...,
                kwds: Mapping[str, Any] = ...,
                callback: Optional[(_T) -> None] = ...,
                error_callback: Optional[(BaseException) -> None] = ...)
```

Your call to `apply_async` should look like this:

```
pool.apply_async(testMethod, args=(t, 'foo', 'bar'))
```

Or, using a keyword argument mapping:

```
pool.apply_async(testMethod, kwds={'arg1': t, 'arg2': 'foo', 'arg3': 'bar'})
```

As an aside: Your code example does not use a thread pool; `multiprocessing.Pool` is a class that represents a *process* pool, i.e. this creates seperate processes to act as workers.
If you want to use a thread pool, go for:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
pool = ThreadPool()
```

The interface is similar to that of the process pool.